# How to deal with computed fields in Entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a question about the best way to deal with computed fields, namely count, in my Entities. I have an Establishment entity that contains reviews, and I don't want to load the reviews until I have to, but I do want to get the number of (count) of reviews when I load the entity object.  What's the best way to handle this?  I've tried creating a numReviews field and and annotating it @Transient, but am having some problems with the session being closed when I called getReviews().size().  I want to know if this is the correct approach to take or if there is a better pattern to follow?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ESTABLISHMENT")
public class Establishment {
...
private Set<Review> reviews = new HashSet<Review>();
...
//Make this extra lazy so we can do a count without loading all the things
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "establishment")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
    public Set<Review> getReviews() {
        return reviews;
    }
    public void setReviews(Set<Review> reviews) {
        this.reviews = reviews;
    }

    @Transient
    public int getNumReviews(){
        if(this.numReviews == null){
            numReviews = this.getReviews().size();
        }
        return numReviews;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Correct` may be opinable. My first idea would be moving all your hibernate operations to a DAO layer and ensuring there, when retrieving the object, that the data is loaded, but it may be heavy

Alternatively, I would use `FetchType.EAGER`.

If that still does not suit you, use HQL to do  (sorry is there is some mistake, I am more used to JPQL)

```
SELECT est, COUNT(rev) FROM Establishment est inner join est.reviews rev ....
```

And when retrieving the values set each object retrieved its totals.